# Develop a custom editable Visual Web Part (WebPart) for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I want to develop a webpart that allows editors to amend its content using Sharepoint's Ribbon-based formatting controls, and then display that content in a nicely formatted way. The built-in content editor webpart isn't sufficient because I want to wrap the content in hardcoded HTML so as to enforce my site's graphical design. Also, I would like the web part to potentially contain more than one editable area, and the standard Content Editor webpart only has one.

My ideal would be a visual web part with a predefined HTML layout, with some editable "content areas" to allow modification in edit mode. When the webpart is saved it will just render its content areas as HTML. I have tried using `<SharePoint:RichTextField>` blocks in a visual web part ascx template but I don't think this is correct. Can anyone give advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, nobody had an answer so I had to do it myself :)

http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2010/09/develop-custom-editable-visual-web-part.html

Comment: Awesome - would be great to port this to 2013